# reading a text file stored as bytes

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

I have a text file where items are stored as bytes, i.e. `b" Charg\xc3\xa9e de mission communication chez BRL Groupe"`. How do I read that into python so that I can decode it into utf-8?

Reading it into python as 'rb' converts it to `b'b" Charg\\xc3\\xa9e de mission communication chez BRL Groupe"'`.

```
with open('bytes.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

I'd like to get it so that it prints the decoded string, `Chargée de mission communication chez BRL Groupe`

Comment: do you have data with hex codes `c3` and `0a9e` in you file or the ascii representation `\xc3` as a four characters: ` \\`, `x`, `c`, `3` ?

Comment: I figured it out. I have to use ast.literal_eval, then decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than decode, which will transform the string to bytes, you need to use something that evaluates the string for what it is. That is ast.literal_eval()

```
print(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

Thanks for downvoting! Here is the answer!